# Php laravel how to get unique values beside one condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like this in my table:

```
id |MIT_ID| type| date | updated_at|
1  | 1    | 2  | ...   | ....     |
2  | 1    |1  | ...  |  ...     |
3  | 1    |3  | ...  |  ...     |
4  | 1    |4  | ...  |  ...     |
5  | 1    |4  | ...  |  ...     |
6  | 1    |2  | ...  |  ...     |
7  | 1    |2  | ...  |  ...     |
```

and I want to orderby update_at and get unique_values beside type 2 so everthing else should return only one value but type 2 should get two rows back.
I tried something like this:

```
 $entry = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->where('MIT_ID', '=', $MIT_ID)->get();
 $entry = $entry->unique('type_id');
 or using distinct didnt work neither.

Desired values:

id| type| date | updated_at|
1  |  2  | ...   | ....     |
2  | 1  | ...  |  ...     |
3  | 3  | ...  |  ...     |
4  | 4  | ...  |  ...     |
6  | 2  | ...  |  ...     |
```

Is there a way to do that? Everything else unique but only one value not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What logic are you using to get 2 out of 3 rows for type 2 and just 1 for other types? Out of the many results of each type, how do you select which specific ones will show up in the result?

Comment: @apokryfos i was thinking using distinct or count but it wouldnt really work that way

Comment: I'm more puzzled at how you determine which row of e.g. type 1 will be selected to "represent" the entire type 1. Also why do you have 2 rows of type 3 out of the possible 3 instead of e.g. 1 or all 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use following methods to get unique values:

 using Group By
 $entry = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->where('MIT_ID', '=', 
               $MIT_ID)->groupBy('type_id')->get();
Using Distinct
$entry = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->where('MIT_ID', '=', 
           $MIT_ID)->distinct('type_id')->get();
using pluck
$entry = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->where('MIT_ID', '=', 
           $MIT_ID)->pluck('type_id')->get();

#####Altered#####
$entry = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->where('MIT_ID', '=', 
       $MIT_ID)->get();
$entry->map(function($e) use $isRepeat {
  if( ($e->type_id!=2 & $isRepeat ==1) OR ($e->type_id ==2 and $isRepeat < 2)){
        return $e;   }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! but how can i say, i want only type 2 for two time other ones only one? cause those I will get all the entries

Comment: you can use map function to alter the result. i have edit the answer. check that